# Beaglebone Black (deabian): running simple PySide code but getting "cannot connect to x server" error

Tags: python, pyside, beagleboneblack

I am trying to run simple PySide code, which is perfectly running on ubuntu, on BeagleBone black(debian wheezy) . I followed the same steps as it is stated in pySide home page for installation for debian. But getting "cannot connect to X server"error while compiling python code. My code is

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv) ---> after this line i am getting that error message.
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I searched for solution on the internet but was not able to find appropriate solution for running pyside code on BBB. I read this [link](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-197). Someone was able to use Pyside in embedded environments by using Qws. But I could not find any links. Could you please help me resolve this issue? I also asked [this question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/beagleboard/cannot$20connect$20to$20x$20server/beagleboard/wDuMMRWeGzM/Yt1vlPydeOgJ) on Beaglebone black google group.

Answer (score 0):

Success. Solved this problem. To be able to access X server I just needed to run the code as a normal user not as a root user. So I ssh'ed to beaglebone black as a "debian" user and ran the code. It was simple pyside code without any integration with GPIO's or I2C'es. In case you want to access/modify these pins you must deal with privileges of "debian" user.